# some arm inline assembly

Tags: gcc, arm

I have arm assembly question.
what is the hex binary output of the following armv7 assembly code?

```
LDR r3, #0xaabbccdd
BLX r3
```

I need the assembler output of this code fragment
 but I have poor computer environment

Thank you in advance

Comment: This won't compile. You can't have `LDR r3, #0xaabbccdd` in a single instruction, since an arm instruction can be 16 or 32 bit, it won't allow you to load 32 bit value at the same time.

Comment: Please state the question in a form that is either "I have this problem and want to know how best to solve it." or "why does this approach not work?". Your current question is somewhere in between, giving little confidence that any answer I gave would actually be of any practical use to you.

Comment: @unixsmurf I thought he just wanted to get binary encoding of those two instructions, and I voted close.

Comment: sorry, this is in fact a bad question. I needed to know the binary encoding of those assembly code ASAP, but only thing I could use was the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by the commenters `LDR r3,#0xaabbccdd` is not a valid instruction. Immediates in ARM opcodes are on the form `ZeroExtend(imm8) ROR (imm4*2)`, which would allow you to represent e.g. `0xaa000000`, `0x00bb0000` and even `0xd000000d` - but not e.g. `0xaabb0000` or `0xaabbccdd`.
Assemblers typically provide a pseudo-instruction for loading 32-bit immediates, e.g. in GAS you can do:

```
ldr r3,=0xaabbccdd
```

Which would be encoded as a PC-relative load - i.e. `ldr r3,[pc,#offset]`. The offset (and therefore the exact instruction encoding) depends on the distance from the instruction to the [literal pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_pool) where the value is stored.

Comment: thank you its very helpful. I know that single ARM instruction can not load a 32bit imm value into register. I was wondering how the assembler will handle this pseudo instruction.